# add required attribute if given id is found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added required attribute dynamically to my form and its working fine, but i want to add required true if `id="mycity"` is found otherwise it could be false.

It is possible in javascript? can anyone Give me suggestion.

*I have so many fields in my form, this is just for demo*

here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<body>


<form action="demo_form.asp">

  <select name="city" id="mycity">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>

   <select name="state">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit">
</form>


<script>
$(function(){
       $("select").prop('required',true);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So **all** `select` elements will be required if there's an `id="mycity"` element present on the page, and not required if there isn't? That seems a bit odd...

Comment: are you sure you have comman id for all 'select' elements. It doesn't make  sense to have common id as in this case only 1st element will be selected

Comment: IDs sould be unique!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this way

```
$("select[id='mycity']")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="demo_form.asp">

  <select name="city" id="mycity">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>

   <select name="state">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit">
</form>


<script>
$(function(){
       $("select[id='mycity']").prop('required',true);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.attr()`

```
$(function(){
   $("#mycity").attr('required',true);
});
```

```js
$(function(){
   $("#mycity").attr('required',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="demo_form.asp">

  <select name="city" id="mycity">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>

   <select name="state">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a test for whether you can find the element:

```
$(function(){
    if ($("#mycity").length) {
       $("select").prop('required',true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if element is `present` using `.length`

```
if($("#mycity").length > 0)
  $("select").prop('required',true);
```